# Page not found for custom post type UI plugin and taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, 404-error, user-interface

I am using [Custom post type UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) and when I try to go to the post created under the post type projects page is redirected to page not found page. I have page created with same name before but I have changed that page name to other name and also parmalink. I have also created custom taxonomy named but when I tried to list the projects under post type projects page not found page is displayed. I found that to make taxonomy work i have created different pages like taxonomy-taxname.php and also tried creating taxonomy.php but the page redirected to page not found. Can anyone suggest me the solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

If you just visit your permalinks setting page, it'll flush the rewrite rules as well.

Comment: Thanks helenhoursandi!! I think the problem was with the same name of page and custom post type. It worked for me changing the page name. But there is still problem with custom taxonomy. The list of post under the taxonomy is listed with file name taxonomy.php but when I go to next page e.g. http://www.hostname.com/taxonomy/taxonomytype/page/2 again page is redirected to page not found page i.e. 404 page. When I set the parmalink to default it does not work. Do anyone has solution for this one.

Answer (score 0):

"flush" your permalinks. Google wordpress custom posttypes 404

or see

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-permalinks-404-and-flushing-the-rewrite-rules.

Seems to catch everyone, luckily Dr google normally has the answer.